# CSS loading spinner animation by changing opacity

Tags: css, sass, css-animations

I have to do a loading spinner that consists of 5 circles and changes it opacity by time.

[image]

I am a newbie with css-animations and I looking for an adviсe.
I did it that way:

Added 5 circles with classes

```
<div className="loading-spinner">
  <div className="dot dot1" />
  <div className="dot dot2" />
  <div className="dot dot3" />
  <div className="dot dot4" />
  <div className="dot dot5" />
</div>
```

These are styles for spinner:

```
.loading-spinner
    .dot
        display: inline-block
        height: 8px
        width: 8px
        margin: 0 5px
        border-radius: 50%
        background-color: $ssp-spinner
        animation-duration: 1s
        animation-iteration-count: infinite

    .dot1
        margin-left: 0
        animation-name: spinner1
    .dot2
        animation-name: spinner2
    .dot3
        animation-name: spinner3
    .dot4
        animation-name: spinner4
    .dot5
        margin-right: 0
        animation-name: spinner5


@keyframes spinner1
    0%
        opacity: 1
    20%
        opacity: .8
    40%
        opacity: .6
    60%
        opacity: .4
    80%
        opacity: .2
    100%
        opacity: 0

@keyframes spinner2
    0%
        opacity: .8
    20%
        opacity: .6
    40%
        opacity: .4
    60%
        opacity: .2
    80%
        opacity: 0
    100%
        opacity: 1

@keyframes spinner3
    0%
        opacity: .6
    20%
        opacity: .4
    40%
        opacity: .2
    60%
        opacity: 0
    80%
        opacity: 1
    100%
        opacity: .8

@keyframes spinner4
    0%
        opacity: .4
    20%
        opacity: .2
    40%
        opacity: 0
    60%
        opacity: 1
    80%
        opacity: .8
    100%
        opacity: .6

@keyframes spinner5
    0%
        opacity: .2
    20%
        opacity: 0
    40%
        opacity: 1
    60%
        opacity: .8
    80%
        opacity: .6
    100%
        opacity: .4
```

Here you can find how it works now [snippet](https://codesandbox.io/s/young-haze-1nief).

Setting a new animation rule for every circle seems wrong and verbose to me.
I would appreciate it if you could help me figure out how to do it right.

Thank!

**UPDATE to @Sheraff answer:**
I modified animation rule with following to do opacity changing more explicit.

That's how I've done it:

```
@keyframes spinner
    0%
        opacity: .2
    25%
        opacity: .4
    50%
        opacity: .6
    75%
        opacity: .8
    100%
        opacity: 1
```

Comment: Please include a minimal, concrete and verifiable example in the question itself instead of linking to a third party site.

Comment: Also, you should add to your question what you want the result to be, because looking at it, it seems fine to me...

Comment: @Terry I've updated the question with all information on code samples. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, you don't need to define many animations if they are all the same. Just use `animation-delay`!

```css
@keyframes spinner { from { opacity: 1; } to { opacity: 0; } }
.dot { animation-name: spinner; }
.dot1 { animation-delay: 0; }
.dot2 { animation-delay: .2s; }
.dot3 { animation-delay: .4s; }
.dot4 { animation-delay: .6s; }
.dot5 { animation-delay: .8s; }
```

I encourage you to look at the MDN doc for [css animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation) to see in more details the cool things you can do!

Comment: Super clear and nice! Thanks a lot for this. I just modify animation rule itself to do opacity changing more explicit. Updated quetion with it!